Google Cloud Vertex AI: CONSUMER_INVALID 403 error in WordPress for text summarization
In My WordPress, I am creating a text summarization function using the below function:
function call_vertex_ai($text_to_summarize) {

    // Get the access token using the service account
    $serviceAccountFile = (PLUGIN_PATH . 'vertex_sa.json');
    $accessToken = getAccessToken($serviceAccountFile);

    // Google Cloud project details
    $project = 'my-posts-data-optimization';
    $location = 'us-central1';
    $publisher = 'google';
    $model = 'gemini-1.5-flash-002';

    // Prepare the API endpoint and payload
    $endpoint = "https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/'.$project.'/locations/'.$location.'/publishers/'.$publisher.'/models/'.$model.':predict";

    $requestBody = [
        "instances" => [
            ["content" => $text_to_summarize]
        ],
        "parameters" => [
            "temperature" => 0.7,
            "maxOutputTokens" => 100, // Ensure a 100-word limit or equivalent in tokens
            "topP" => 0.8,
            "topK" => 40
        ]
    ];

    // Make the cURL request to the Gemini model
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestBody));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($httpCode == 200) {
        $responseBody = json_decode($response, true);
        return $responseBody['predictions'][0]['content']; // Return the summarized text
    } else {
        error_log("Error with the request. HTTP Code: $httpCode");
        return "Error: Unable to summarize text.";
    }
}

In IAM, principal php-call@my-posts-data-optimization.iam.gserviceaccount.com has been assigned AI Platform Admin  & Vertex AI user  roles.
What's working are:
$serviceAccountFile path is correct, and the credentials in the file are valid.
$accessToken returns a valid token.
$text_to_summarize is passed to this function from another function and has valid content.
I am getting the following 403 errors:
"message": "Permission denied on resource project '.my-posts-data-optimization.'.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
 "reason": "CONSUMER_INVALID",
What could be the potential mistakes I need to correct to make this function work?

Your question is not a minimal repro making it more difficult for us to help. You don't include (facts for) any of the background work, that the Project exists, that the Service Account exists, that the IAM bindings are correct, that Vertex service is enabled. You're compounding your difficulty by hand-crafting the REST calls rather than use one of Google's client libraries.

I'd also suggest removing the WordPress tag as the code has nothing to do with WordPress, but general PHP.

After debugging, I found how I constructed the $endpoint with variables is troubling.
Not the permission issues.
Below is the correct one without single quotes:
$endpoint = "https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$project/locations/$location/publishers/$publisher/models/$model:predict";
